# Resume for a second career already in progress

Tags: resume, job-search

After some years in sales and sales management, I went back to school for computer science and after a couple of years in that program I left it for an software job that I've now been at for almost 5 years. Although I didn't finish the CS degree, I do have a bachelor's from years ago.

Now I'm curious how to proceed with my resume:

- I can list everything even though only my most recent job/university experience will likely be relevant to prospective employers.
- I can only list the most recent job/schooling.
- I can take a middle way by mentioning previous career/degree without spelling everything out in detail.

I ask this question because everything I found while searching was geared towards people *looking* to make a career change (which I've already done). How should I write this?

Comment: The industry job is a different field than computer science and sales, correct?

Comment: @TheRealLester no I'm a software engineer. And I love it, have no intention of changing careers again. I'm just trying to resurrect my personal website after a couple year hiatus and wondering how to write the resume portion. I edited the question to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: @JaredSmith so why are you updating your CV? You plan to look for another job related to software?

Comment: Are you actually linking your resume on your website?  This is much different to a resume that you would send to a company.

Comment: @DarkCygnus looking? Not necessarily. But I've had a couple of friends at start-ups pitch their employers to me and I'd like to at least be able to point to "here's me". Besides, who knows? I got the job I'm in essentially by being available and it finding me :)

Comment: @TheRealLester both.

Comment: Was the uncompleted CS degree a masters degree? Do you have a bachelor's in STEM? As a hiring manager I look at relevant experience more than degree, but certain organizations such as federally funded research and development centers (FFRDCs) have much stricter requirements on degree of study.

Comment: You can make a 4th bullet that you have *some* schooling for CS degree. I notice a lot of jobs list that it is okay to have partial schooling with actual experience to back it up.

Comment: @jcmack my bachelor's is in English, the second degree was me working on the prereqs for a master's in CS by completing the necessary undergraduate coursework.

Comment: @JaredSmith English -> CS is more common than most would think. In that case, I would recommend listing that you have an uncompleted masters in CS on your resume. Since you have work experience as a software engineer already, you probably don't need to list your coursework. Be prepared though that some manager may ask why you didn't chose to complete your masters degree.

Comment: @jcmack I have no trouble talking about why I didn't finish my masters, but I'm a little reluctant to claim "unfinished masters in CS" when I haven't completed the undergraduate coursework necessary for admission to a masters program. Maybe I'll just say I have an unfinished bachelor's in CS (which is technically true).

Comment: @JaredSmith That's tricky one. Unless upon completion of the prerequisite courses for a masters admission you will receive a bachelor's where you live, you technically don't have an unfinished bachelors degree in CS. I'm going to assume you live in the US. For US, it's not common to start another bachelors rather than start a masters of CS degree instead. I would list your bachelors in English and list CS coursework you completed. The coursework you did is very similar to just taking for credit classes at a local university or an online course outside of a degree program.

Comment: @jcmack in the course of doing the prereq work I applied for (and was accepted to) the undergraduate CS program as a backup in case I didn't get in to the masters program (which I intended to complete if I failed to get into the masters program), so I do (as far as I know) have an unfinished bachelors in CS. Claiming an unfinished masters is a bit more of a stretch than I'm willing to make though.

Comment: @JaredSmith Interesting. It's about what you're comfortable with and if it is technically true. It sounds like you were accepted to the bachelors program and completed some kind of coursework. To me, listing unfinished bachelors in CS is likely okay. If you want to be extra sure, I would check with your school if you were enrolled as a degree-seeking student (and for which degree) or a non-degree seeking student (e.g. professional development). It's a nuance, but could be important for degree verification purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are transitioning, it is important to list your previous experience, even if it is not relevant, but you may want to abridge your **irrelevant experience**  in those positions.

To bolster your resume, try to do some charity work in your new chosen profession, as charity work always looks good, and it also gives you additional experience.

It's better to have someone say "Oh, this person is changing careers" than "What has this person been doing"

Additionally, try to make your previous experience more relevant to your chosen field.  Emphasize how your experience in sales management translates to problem solving in computer science.  Retool your past experience to bring out problems you solved and how your analytical skills, problem solving, and trouble-shooting abilities translate.

I.E.

- How you used your analytical skills to improve sales
- How you fixed flagging sales
- How you stayed on top of trends
- Managing staff and any logistics.

Comment: I don't mind adding the relevant stuff from my prior career, but after 5 years in software do I need to pad out my employment history with charity work? I don't have any employment gaps other than the full-time CS studies at university which is pretty easy to explain.

Comment: @JaredSmith I prefer to cover all bases.  You know what is best for you.  I'm just presenting you with everything I know to do.  I went from being a road sign maker at the road department to becoming a computer programmer, BTW, so I know how to transition.

Comment: If I knew what was best for me I wouldn't be asking for advice from strangers on the internet. I will take yours under advisement :)

Comment: @JaredSmith Fair enough.  If you can do charity work, it always looks good and may just up your chances a bit more.  I like to use a scatter-shot approach, to do everything I can to up my chances.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a reason to not put your previous experience in the workplace on your CV. At the very least it will show you are motivated and have experiences which may put you ahead of other potential candidates.

Depending on the company you apply to, they may need somebody with experience of sales. It could lead to faster promotion depending on the product you are building.